# Is it OK to have multiple Selects on the same page with Ant Design?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

Currently I have multiple Ant Design Select dropdowns on a single page. Whenever I select a value from one, the others become unclickable. It's not clear why this is, here's my code:

```
{ 
     Object.keys(mapping).map((m, index) => {
         if(m === 'available' || mapping[m]['name'] == 'Price'){
         return null
        }

     let available = mapping[m] ? mapping[m].available ? mapping[m].available : [] : []
     if(available.length === 0){
      return null
     }

     return <Col md={4} xs={12} key={index}>
      <Tooltip title={`Include only ${mapping[m].name} results`}>
         <Select defaultValue={mapping[m].name} style={{ width: "100%", padding: '3px 10px' }} 
     onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e, m)} key={mapping[m].name + index}
     >
         {
             available.map(value => {
                 return <Option value={value} key={mapping[m].name + value}>{value}</Option>
             })
         }

          </Select>
          </Tooltip>
     </Col>
 })
```

}

For explanation, the code looks through a list of categories for dropdowns, and displays the values from a list of values from the Available feed for each of the categories.

Is there something with how the select button is referenced that is causing them to all interact with each other in this way?

Comment: Hey Dan, your code is unreadable, you should add a [minimal presentation of your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) if you can add a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/antdstart-n8n96).

Comment: Agreed, a sandbox would be preferable but we at least need to see how you're handling your state and changes